# Unicode version for Delphi (XE2)

Tags: delphi, unicode, migration, delphi-xe2, delphi-2007

We are upgrading our application from Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE2, which includes unicode support as well.

Our desired unicode version support is 3.2 and above.

Which Unicode version does Delphi (XE2) support?

Comment: Which particular aspects of the Unicode standard are you looking for support for?

Comment: See this [MS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drintl/archive/2005/06/01/unicodequestion.aspx) about Unicode version support in Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi does not support any specific Unicode version, it just relies on OS Unicode API. So check what Unicode version is supported by Windows.